# what are package variables in golang declared without a type

Tags: go, variables

I am new to golang and fairly new to programming. While reading the golang documentation I came across variables declared without type associated to it.

eg: **var StdEncoding = NewEncoding(encodeStd)**

I can this in the encode/base64 package. I am not sure what it means. I know that you need to mention that type while declaring variables but this one doesnt have any type. How are these variables different from other and how do I use them?

Comment: See the [Tour of Go](https://go.dev/tour/basics/9) and [the language specification](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Variable_declarations).  If the type is not present, then the variable is given the type of corresponding initialization value in the assignment.  In the question's example, the [initialization value](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/base64#NewEncoding) has type `*Encoding`.

Answer (score 1):

in golang, we must specify the type for each variable. if you use `var` keyword you can declare variable without assign the value, but you must declare the type also.

```
var a int
a = 10
```

but if you use `var` keyword to declare a variable and directly assign the value to it, you have option to declare the type or not. if not, golang will decide the type base on the value assigned to variable. In your example because `NewEncoding` will return `*Encoding` so type of variable `stdEncoding` will be `Encoding` struct.

```
var a int = 10 // you can do this
var a = 10 // also, you can do this
```

Comment: thank you for the concise explanation. that helps. My last question is how/when are these variables used?

I came across one example here: 

fmt.Println(base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte("user:pass")))

I have a general understanding what is happening here but i had to write this myself, I would be stuck since I dont understand the details of it

Comment: if your concern is about how/when to use the variable, I think it like other usecase of variable. the variable used to store the value or instance so you can use it multiple times. But if your concern is more specific to usage of package `encoding/base64` honestly I don't have enough knowledge to talk about it.

Comment: So I figured usage about the encoding/base64 package. There are 4 ways to encode data and hence there are 4 variables (https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/base64#pkg-variables).